# Why am I forced to put a first line commentary in validators.en.yml?

Tags: symfony

I have an entity with the following annotation

```
@Assert\Callback(methods={"checkValidity"})
```

And the method, under a condition adds an error :

```
public function checkValidity(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if ($this->getAmount() < $this->getMinimumAmount()) {
        $context->buildViolation('app.forms.transfer.errors.amountLowerThanMinimum')
            ->atPath('amount')
            ->setParameter('%minimumAmount%', $this->getMinimumAmount())
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

To make it work, I have to put theses lines in validator.en.yml

```
# line: foo
app:
    forms:
        transfer:
            errors:
                balanceTooLow: Your balance is too low to transfer %amount% to %application%
                amountLowerThanMinimum: The application %application% required that you transfer a minimum of $%minimumAmount%
```

It works perfectly, but if I remove this first dummy line

```
# line: foo
```

It doesn't translate my error anymore.

After searching for an explanation during an entire hour, I still don't understand what could explain this strange behaviour. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you clearing the cache after modifying the catalogue?

Comment: I tried clearing the cache, it doesn't make any difference.